# delegate, replace and fade / jQuery

Tags: jquery

A jQuery related question - I have a little gallery style script working - a list of thumbnails and associated larger images switching on thumbnail click, like so:

```
$('#thumbs').delegate('img','click', function(){
    $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
});
```

My question is: what's the easiest way of making the image transitions fade between one another rather than a straight switch?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.come/fadeOut) the image, then [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.come/fadeIn) in the callback after swapping the `src`:

```
$('#thumbs').delegate('img','click', function(){
    var src = this.src.replace('thumb', 'large');
    $("#largeImage").fadeOut(function() {
        this.src = src;
        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/edihum) using our gravatars | [source](http://jsbin.com/edihum/edit)

(Note that there's no need to go through `attr` for `src`; it's [reflected](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-87762984) on the DOM element.)

Answer (score 1):

The *easiest* way would be to use one of the jQuery cycle plugins that exist. The one @ [malsup.com](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) is a popular choice.

If you want to code it yourself, you'll have to use 2 image elements and position one behind the other, and fade out the one on top.

You can do this by using a `position: relative`  on the parent of the `<img />` and a `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;` on the `<img />`. After you've faded the top image out [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut), you can remove it in the callback:

```
$('img_on_top').fadeOut('slow', function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#thumbs').delegate('img','click', function(){
    var src = $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large');
    $('#largeImage').fadeOut(100,function() {
      $(this).attr('src',src).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: Wrong `this` in the callback. (Ah, you've fixed it now. :-) )